# How to parse through Dictionary with nested list using Python

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, nested

PYTHON - Parsin Through Dictionary

Currently have a Dictionary that is structured as such

```
data =
{
     "Invitees": [
    {
           "firstName": "Will",
           "lastName": "Klein",
           "email": "WKlein@***il.com",
           "highSchool": "NorthwestHS",
           "availableDates": [
               "2018-02-01",
               "2018-02-02"
           ]
     },
     {
           "firstName": "Jack",
           "lastName": "Smith"
           "email": "JSmith@***il.com",
           "highSchool": "SouthwestHS",
           "availableDates": [
                "2018-02-04",
                "2018-01-01"
            ]
     },
     {
           "firstName": "Jamie",
           "lastName": "Farough",
           "email": "JFarough@***il.com",
           "highSchool": "NorthwestHS",
           "availableDates": [
                "2018-02-01",
                "2018-02-02"
           ]
     },
     {
           "firstName": "Bob",
           "lastName": "Saggot",
           "email": "BSaggot@***il.com",
           "highSchool": "NorthwestHS",
           "availableDates": [
               "2018-02-01",
               "2018-02-02"
           ]
     }
}
```

I want to invite people to my 2-day Birthday Party, but I have to pick a date that best works for the individuals (indexed by their HS). The goal is create a program that can index the Dictionary and return which people can attend based on the dates their availability (2 consecutive days). Right now I created a list detailing the information of each person, but am not sure how to combine them by their available dates.
I have:

```
for index in range(lengthofDic):
     highSchool.append(data["Attendee"][index]["highSchool"])
     email.append(data["Attendee"][index]["email"])
     availDate.append(data["Attendee"][index]["availableDates"])
```

Which gives the different list containing the information for each person, but I dont know how to combine and filter the list in order to find the best 2 dates that work for people at the same school.

Also tried a function below to filter out the same dates between different values in the list, but dont know how to do it for more than 2 list:

```
 for index in range(lengthofDic):
      print (lamda x,y: x in (availableDate[1]), (availableDate[1]))  #availableDate is list containing dates
```

An example of the output that I would want is below:

```
{
    "Attendee": [
    {
        "aCount": 3,
        "attendees": [
            "BSaggot@***il.com"                
            "JFarough@***il.com"
            "WKlein@***il.com
        ],
        "highSchool": "NorthwestHS",
        "startDate": "2018-02-01"
    },
    {
        "aCount": 0,
        "attendees": [],
        "highSchool": "SouthWestHS,
        "startDate": null
    }
```

Southwest High School could not attend because the attendee(s) from that school did not have any consecutive 2 day availability so it returned NULL. Any advice on how to structure the program or what methods to use would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please fix the code formatting

Comment: Would you mind removing all the whitespace from the code?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JSON, this is a dictionary.